# How to optimize this query?

Tags: sql, mysql

**prices**
    id
    id_stock
    price
    date

```
**stocks**
id
stock_name
active
```

now i have to set `stocks.active=0` for each stocks that has the `MAX(prices.date) > 15 days` (of a date i have to pass)

This is my query, but it's very very slow!!!

```
update stocks set stocks.active=0 where stocks.id IN (

SELECT prices.id_stock 
FROM prices
GROUP BY prices.id_stock
HAVING datediff('2010-08-17', MAX( prices.date )) > 15

)
```

How to optimize it?

Thank you really much!

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE  stocks
SET     active = 0
WHERE   DATEDIFF('2010-08-17',
        (
        SELECT  MAX(prices.date)
        FROM    prices
        WHERE   id_stock = stocks.id
        )) > 15
```

Create an index on `prices (id_stock, date)`

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find rewriting the `IN` clause as an `EXISTS` improves matters...

```
UPDATE stocks SET stocks.active=0
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prices.id_stock 
                      FROM prices
                      WHERE prices.id_stock = stocks.id
                      GROUP BY prices.id_stock
                      HAVING datediff('2010-08-17', MAX( prices.date )) > 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update stocks
Set active = 0
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From prices
                Where prices.id_stock = stocks.Id
                Having Max(prices.date) < DateAdd( '2010-08-17', Interval -15 Day)
                )
```